# Retrieving data from json using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat, getjson

I am learning angular js from ground up and am currently trying to retrieve data from a json file.

I am using - nodejs, express, AngularJS.

Earlier I was getting an error "Unexpected token D" on using -

```
$http.get("/models/driversList.json").success(function(response){$scope.driversList = response})
```

which got resolved but now I'm getting something like this with the current code -

```
Drivers Championship Standings
1
```

I'm guessing the response is basically blank and therefore the "1" but am not getting as to why that is happening.

Below are my files -

> /app.js

```
app.use('/models',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'private/data/db/models')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/scripts',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/javascripts')));
app.use('/styles',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public/stylesheets')));
```

---

> /javascripts/app.js

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp', [
  'F1FeederApp.controllers'
]);
```

---

> /javascripts/controllers.js

```
angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).
controller('driversController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/models/driversList.json',
    data: {},
    transformResponse: function (data, headersGetter, status) {
        //This was implemented since the REST service is returning a plain/text response
        //and angularJS $http module can't parse the response like that.
        return {data: data};
    }
}).success(function(response){ alert('worked'); $scope.driversList = response}).error(function(response) {
    $scope.driversList = [
      {
          Driver: {
              givenName: response,
              familyName: 'Vettel'
          },
          points: 322,
          nationality: "German",
          Constructors: [
              {name: "Red Bull"}
          ]
      },
      {
          Driver: {
          givenName: 'Fernando',
              familyName: 'Alonso'
          },
          points: 207,
          nationality: "Spanish",
          Constructors: [
              {name: "Ferrari"}
          ]
      }
    ];
})  
});
```

---

> driversList.json

```
[
      {
          Driver: {
              givenName: 'Eldorado',
              familyName: 'Vettel'
          },
          points: 322,
          nationality: "German",
          Constructors: [
              {name: "Red Bull"}
          ]
      },
      {
          Driver: {
          givenName: 'Fernando',
              familyName: 'Alonso'
          },
          points: 207,
          nationality: "Spanish",
          Constructors: [
              {name: "Ferrari"}
          ]
      }
    ]
```

---

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>F-1 Feeder</title>
  <script src="/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="F1FeederApp" ng-controller="driversController">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="4">Drivers Championship Standings</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
      <tr ng-repeat="driver in driversList">
        <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
        <td>
          {{driver.Driver.givenName}}&nbsp;{{driver.Driver.familyName}}
        </td>
        <td>{{driver.Constructors[0].name}}</td>
        <td>{{driver.points}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**:

---

@rattanak

To answer the point 3, yes it works if I simply assign the array variable to the scope variable. The part in error() is the one which was working previously.

I also tried point 1 and it seems the json is present in "data", so I assigned response.data to driversList and now am getting this error -

```
Data:
[{Driver:{givenName:'Eldorado',familyName:'Vettel'},points:322,nationality:"German",Constructors:[{name:"Red Bull"}]}]

Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=driver%20in%20driversList.data&p1=string%3Ar&p2=r
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:280:39
    at Object.fn (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:129:401)
    at n.a.$get.n.$digest (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:130:483)
    at n.a.$get.n.$apply (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:133:512)
    at h (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:87:376)
    at K (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:91:499)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (http://localhost:3000/scripts/angular.min.js:93:37)
```

indicating that there are duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file driverlist.json does not contain valid JSON code. This code should be:

```
[
  {
      "Driver": {
          "givenName": "Eldorado",
          "familyName": "Vettel" },
      "points": 322,
      "nationality": "German",
      "Constructors": [
          {"name": "Red Bull"}
       ]
  },
  {
      "Driver": {
        "givenName": "Fernando",
        "familyName": "Alonso"
      },
      "points": 207,
      "nationality": "Spanish",
      "Constructors": [
          {"name": "Ferrari"}
      ]
  }
]
```

Correct this and try again.

JSON always use double quotes (") never single quotes (')

For more info on correct JSON, see http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the $http service does not resolve successfully. It is hard to tell without actually testing the code. With Chrome Dev Console, I would debug the code by:

1. Use `console.log($scope.driversList)` in the success function of the promise.
2. Use `console.log(error)` in the error function of the promise.
3. Were you able to get the code to work without using $http service, namely just assign array variable of the data to `$scope.driversList`.

I am happy to test it for you if you can provide a github link or something.